# Custom metrics using active TLS connections for AKS HPA

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, hpa

I am running a service in AKS pods that would establish TLS connections with the client. There is a hard limit of 5K active connections per pod. I need a way to determine number of active TLS connections per pod and auto scale (HPA) when it reaches a threshold (say 3.5K TLS connections) and scale down when active connections are below 1K.

Is there a way to collect such metrics in AKS and scale based on that metrics. Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

**By default, scale-up operations performed manually or by the cluster autoscaler require the allocation and provisioning of new nodes, and scale-down operations delete nodes. Scale-down Mode allows you to decide whether you would like to delete or deallocate the nodes in your Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) cluster upon scaling down.**

> There is not any microsoft document that autoscale based on TLS
> connection per pod.

Kubernetes has a **`cluster autoscaler`**, that adjusts the number of nodes based on the requested compute resources in the node pool. By default, the cluster autoscaler checks the Metrics API server every 10 seconds for any required changes in node count. If the cluster autoscale determines that a change is required, the number of nodes in your AKS cluster is increased or decreased accordingly. The cluster autoscaler works with Kubernetes RBAC-enabled AKS clusters that run Kubernetes 1.10.x or higher.

Cluster autoscaler is typically used alongside the horizontal pod autoscaler. When combined, the horizontal pod autoscaler increases or decreases the number of pods based on application demand, and the cluster autoscaler adjusts the number of nodes as needed to run those additional pods accordingly.

To get started with the cluster autoscaler in AKS, see [***Cluster Autoscaler on AKS.***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/cluster-autoscaler)

***Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/concepts-scale#cluster-autoscaler***

**For Counting the TLS connection to particuler nodes can be done using `Plateform metrics` ->`Microsoft.Blockchain/blockchainMembers`->`ClusterCommEgressTlsConnectionCount`**

You can refer the [***same***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/metrics-supported#exporting-platform-metrics-to-other-locations) here.